# 'UIColor!' is not identical to 'SKColor'

Tags: swift

Can someone please explain why if, as it says in the import definition:

```
typealias SKColor = UIColor
```

I get the error 'UIColor!' is not identical to 'SKColor' when I do the following? I was about to say 'I know the difference between UIColor and UIColor!' but actually, maybe I don't truly understand!

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

func nColours(gradient: [SKColor]) -> Int {
    return gradient.count
}

let gradient = [SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.magentaColor()]
nColours([SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.magentaColor()]) // 2, OK
nColours(gradient) //  <<<<<< Error 
// 'UIColor!' is not identical to 'SKColor'
```

experimenting, I tried this :

```
let gradient = [SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.magentaColor()]
let b = (gradient == [SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.magentaColor()]) // <<<<<< Error 
// '[UIColor!]' is not convertible to '_ArrayCastKind'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `UIColor` and `UIColor!` are technically different types - the `!` stands for [Implicitly Unwrapped Optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_435) and is used where there is an optional value, but that optional should *always* have a value.

It seems that many objects returned from the system frameworks use implicitly optional types, though this usage should get less common as the frameworks are fully converted to Swift - there's no reason UIColor.redColor() would ever return a nil color, so its return type will probably change from `SKColor!` to `SKColor` in the future.

In your code example, if you change your `let gradient` declaration to explicitly declare the array as being of type `[SKColor]` (as opposed to `SKColor!`) the compiler happily carries on:

```
let gradient : [SKColor] = [SKColor.redColor(), SKColor.magentaColor()]
```